# How to pick a random property from an object without repeating after multiple calls?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pick a random film from an object containing film objects. I need to be able to call the function repeatedly getting distinct results until every film has been used.

I have this function, but it doesn't work because the outer function returns with nothing even if the inner function calls itself because the result is not unique.

```
var watchedFilms = [];
$scope.watchedFilms = watchedFilms;

var getRandomFilm = function(movies) {
  var moviesLength = Object.keys(movies).length;

  function doPick() {
    var pick = pickRandomProperty(movies);
    var distinct = true;
    for (var i = 0;i < watchedFilms.length; i += 1) {
      if (watchedFilms[i]===pick.title) {
        distinct = false;
        if (watchedFilms.length === moviesLength) {
          watchedFilms = [];
        }
      }
    }

    if (distinct === true) {
      watchedFilms.push(pick.title);
      return pick;
    }

    if (distinct === false) {
      console.log(pick.title+' has already been picked');
      doPick();
    }
  };
  return doPick();
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to modify the film objects? Or alternately, make a random list of them and then just pop one each time...

Comment: Yes, I can modify the film objects

Comment: @user759 What do you want to do once all films have been used? Are you cycling through them once again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: You've said you can modify the `film` objects, so that simplifies things:

```
var getRandomFilm = function(movies) {
  var keys = Object.keys(movies);
  var keyCount = keys.length;
  var candidate;
  var counter = keyCount * 2;

  // Try a random pick
  while (--counter) {
    candidate = movies[keys[Math.floor(Math.random() * keyCount)]];
    if (!candidate.watched) {
      candidate.watched = true;
      return candidate;
    }
  }

  // We've done two full count loops and not found one, find the
  // *first* one we haven't watched, or of course return null if
  // they've all been watched
  for (counter = 0; counter < keyCount; ++counter) {
    candidate = movies[keys[counter]];
    if (!candidate.watched) {
      candidate.watched = true;
      return candidate;
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

This has the advantage that it doesn't matter if you call it with the same `movies` object or not.

Note the safety valve. Basically, as the number of watched films approaches the total number of films, our odds of picking a candidate at random get smaller. So if we've failed to do that after looping for twice as many iterations as there are films, we give up and just pick the first, if any.

---

**Original** *(which doesn't modify film objects)*

If you can't modify the film objects, you do still need the `watchedFilms` array, but it's fairly simple:

```
var watchedFilms = [];
$scope.watchedFilms = watchedFilms;

var getRandomFilm = function(movies) {
  var keys = Object.keys(movies);
  var keyCount = keys.length;
  var candidate;

  if (watchedFilms.length >= keyCount) {
    return null;
  }

  while (true) {
    candidate = movies[keys[Math.floor(Math.random() * keyCount)]];
    if (watchedFilms.indexOf(candidate) === -1) {
      watchedFilms.push(candidate);
      return candidate;
    }
  }
}
```

Note that like your code, this assumes `getRandomFilm` is called with the **same** `movies` object each time.

Comment: Is the safe valve really needed?

Comment: @plalx: How do we know all of the movies aren't `watched`? Without the safety valve, we'd loop forever trying to find one that wasn't. We could do a pre-loop to check, and then proactively return `null`, but there's always the ***small*** chance that if there were only one film unwatched in a list of hundreds or thousands, our pick-a-number loop would take a long time to find it.

Comment: Yes, I should have looked more carefully at the implementation. The function is stateless, so you have no other choice. I guess I would have to add the same kind of safety valve in my own answer then. The easiest way to avoid this issue seems to be cloning the list and splice it as you select random items. However, if you want to avoid returning the same item twice in a row (through cycles), it gets a bit more tricky (if you do not allow to mutate the items like you did), considering that the same object could be in the array multiple times. It seems every solution has it's downsides.

Answer (score 1):

T.J. Crowder already gave a great answer, however I wanted to show an alternative way of solving the problem using OO.

You could create an object that wraps over an array and makes sure that a random unused item is returned everytime. The version I created is cyclic, which means that it infinitely loops over the collection, but if you want to stop the cycle, you can just track how many movies were chosen and stop once you reached the total number of movies.

```
function CyclicRandomIterator(list) {
    this.list = list;
    this.usedIndexes = {};
    this.displayedCount = 0;
}

CyclicRandomIterator.prototype.next = function () {
    var len = this.list.length,
        usedIndexes = this.usedIndexes,
        lastBatchIndex = this.lastBatchIndex,
        denyLastBatchIndex = this.displayedCount !== len - 1,
        index;

    if (this.displayedCount === len) {
        lastBatchIndex = this.lastBatchIndex = this.lastIndex;
        usedIndexes = this.usedIndexes = {};
        this.displayedCount = 0;
    }

    do index = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
    while (usedIndexes[index] || (lastBatchIndex === index && denyLastBatchIndex));

    this.displayedCount++;
    usedIndexes[this.lastIndex = index] = true;

    return this.list[index];
};
```

Then you can simply do something like:

```
var randomMovies = new CyclicRandomIterator(Object.keys(movies));

var randomMovie = movies[randomMovies.next()];
```

Note that the advantage of my implementation if you are cycling through items is that the same item will never be returned twice in a row, even at the beginning of a new cycle.